# UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone even if pushnotification is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hi in my iOS app I am checking pushnotification is enabled or not, in iPad's settings pushnotification for my app is enabled (ALLOW NOTIFICATIONS = yes, and Alert style is Banners).

Eventhough in my app - I am getting notification type as UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone.

```
     UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

   if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone){

     //Enters
    }
```

Also no notification is coming in the device. This happenes only in my iPad and iPods but in iPhone works fine.

Why it is happening, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to register for push notifications has been changed in iOS 8, check below code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

else
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];

}
```